# Does datastore require an ancestor to be specified when querying root and children entities of the same type?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

For example, take the following snippet from the provided [appengine-angular-gotodos](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-angular-gotodos/blob/master/gotodos.go#L89-L99) :

```
func getAllTodos(c appengine.Context) ([]Todo, error) {
    todos := []Todo{}
    ks, err := datastore.NewQuery("Todo").Ancestor(defaultTodoList(c)).Order("Created").GetAll(c, &todos)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(todos); i++ {
        todos[i].Id = ks[i].IntID()
    }
    return todos, nil
}
```

If you change the query to not include `.Ancestor(defaultTodoList(c)).` the function fails to return any todo results.

- If an entity is saved with an ancestry, must you query it by that ancestor?
- How do you query for Entities regardless of whether they are children, or root entities?
- What are the performance and architecture considerations I should make when modeling my app given the need to do ancestor-less queries?

Answer (score 1):

> If an entity is saved with an ancestry, must you query it by that
>   ancestor?

No you don't have to.

> How do you query for Entities regardless of whether they are children,
>   or root entities?

Reduced to as simple an example as possible from [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference):

```
//Assuming c is your appengine context
q = datastore.NewQuery("MyObject") // Can add filters and sorting here if desired.

for t := q.Run(c);; {
    var x MyObject
    key, err := t.Next(&x)
}
```

I also found this note [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Python_Ancestor_queries):

> Note: Setting an ancestor filter allows for strongly consistent
>   queries. Queries without an ancestor filter only return eventually
>   consistent results.

This is important because I believe all datastores are HRD now. You can read more about [high replication datastores](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency).

Comment: Hi Ben. Thanks -- I had a suspicion this had to do with eventual consistency. In practice, I feel like this type of query should be avoided. I'm new to datastore, could you help me better understand the data-modeling considerations involved?

Comment: Basically just because you add/modify data in the datastore on one instance does not guarantee another instance can fetch that data immediately via a query. However a direct "get" will always be consistent. If you require consistency in a query you will have to use the ancestor query

Answer (score 0):

`defaultTodoList(c)` might not contain the parent Entity that the code expects it to contain.  Try to verify its value somehow before using it, for example by storing it in a variable and then [logging](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/#Go_Logging) data out of it.